# Make new user able to login via ssh

Tags: ssh, configuration, authentication, webserver

I have been given a server to use for some computations. I have been given the root password and they told me to create an account for myself.

I accessed the server using `ssh root@host`
and inputing the root password. I then created an user with `sudo useradd -m myname` and set a password. Then I logout, and tried to ssh doing `ssh myname@host`

Immediately after I insert my password, though, my connections gets closed:

```
Connection to host closed by remote host.
Connection to host closed.
```

I tried looking into the host.deny and host.allow files, but they don't seem to be modified (they are commented out with #)

Then I tried looking into `etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I don't know exactly what to look for. These are some of the parameters that seem relevant:

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

What could be the problem?
Note that I am not trying to login using ssh-keys, inserting the password is fine. How can I make that work?

**Edit** This is the content of the whole sshd_config file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

**Edit 2**
Here is the output of the connection attempt with `ssh -vv username@host`

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host_name" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host_name [ip_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to host_name:22 as ‘username_on_server’
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
[…]
debug1: Server host key: [serverkey]
debug1: Host 'host_name' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /localhome/username/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /localhome/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
username_on_server@host_name's password: <——- Here I inserted my password
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to host_name ([ip_address]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to host_name closed by remote host.
Connection to host_name closed.
Transferred: sent 1736, received 1388 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9760471.5, received 7803879.3
debug1: Exit status -1
```

**Edit 3**
the .profile of the new user on the server

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: - Did you either create a password for myname (using passwd), or set a public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys?
- what is there in sshd_config for AllowUsers?

Comment: Try ssh -vvv to see if you can see any error messages. Check the message logs on the server also

Comment: tonioc is correct. You need 1. a password set on the account to unlock it, and 2. public key auth setup for that user. Looks like the box only accepts public key authentication. See how `PasswordAuthentication` is commented out?

Comment: @Patrick - that commented out line just shows the default setting.  To switch it to NO you would need to uncomment it.  So it's likely it does accept passwords, and in fact, in the original question Ant states he logged in user root and a password.

Comment: Use `ssh -vv myname@host` and if you can't see the problem in the output, add the output (formatted) to your question.

Comment: If you log into a system using the root account, you are root afterwards and the use of `sudo` is needless.

Comment: Try to [bypass the profile](https://superuser.com/a/48152/79880): `ssh -t host "bash --noprofile"`

Comment: Doesn't look like PAM is failing. It looks like user session is returning in error somewhere. Check your .profile?

Comment: Test whether you can `ssh` locally: first `ssh` in as root, then `ssh -vv username@localhost` and compare.  Test if you can `ssh` and execute a command without a terminal: `ssh -vv username@host pwd`

Comment: @user4556274 In both cases, I had connection closed by remote host, same as before

Comment: @Ant - if it's a RedHat based distro look in /var/log/secure. Might need to look in systemd's logs for this as well. See if the server tells you why it's disconnecting the connection (if it's the server doing so).

Comment: @slm It is Ubuntu 16.04. Should I look there nonetheless? Sorry if it's obvious, I am not very practical with this :/

Comment: @Ant: Yes look there. It might be /var/log/auth on Ubuntu. Suggest you check there for password check failures.

Comment: It seems to crash, when sshd forks to setup users subprocess. Try setting `LogLevel DEBUG` in sshd_config, reload and look in /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the home directory of the user you're trying to login with was created, that the ownership is also your user, and that ~/.ssh is set to chmod 700.  Also check /var/log/secure for any errors while you're trying to log in.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh -vv` output seems to indicate the password auth was accepted, so it would seem that everything is good up to that point, but there is something happening right after that that is closing the session. Things I would check:

1. Seems obvious but since this is a new user, have you verified the login shell is set to something valid? (i.e. `/bin/bash` and not `nologin` or `notty` etc.)
2. More of a long shot, but check for anything weird in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, etc that could be attempting to execute at login. As @ceving suggests above, you might try an ssh session that does not execute the .profile in your login shell.